# Connectivity between two hosts on the same LAN ( physically )

Tags: networking, switch

I'm sorry but I have a basic question about Networking.
Assuming that we have 2 hosts each one has a different IP on a different network like indicated in the following images.

[image: Switch + 2 PCs on different network]

The question is : can they ping each other and, if no matter the answer, why this happen ?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the switch is an unmanaged one and there's no VLAN whatsoever, all you need to do is to add *direct* routes on the two hosts for the "other" host/network (whichever that suits you needs).

Direct route means the route is composed of a destination host/network address (with subnet mask / prefix length) and a network interface, with no nexthop / gateway address (because no router / gateway will be involved in the communication, but only the switch and ARP that works within the L2 broadcast domain).

With that said though, it's somewhat unusual and probably pointless to use more than one IP subnet within a broadcast domain.

Answer (score 1):

By default, no. "Physically" they would be able to, but they don't know this – their /24 subnet masks tell them that the opposite address is outside of the subnet. (In other words, they only have a route for their own /24, but no routes for any other address.) Since there's no route that would match the opposite address (assuming no default gateway is configured), the most likely result is a "Network unreachable" or "No route to host" error.

A custom route could be added that defines the opposite /24 as "on-link" to inform the OS that packets could be directly sent to the other address:

```
HostA# ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0

HostB# ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
```

(In some other operating systems, such a "direct" route would be added by specifying the source host's own address as the gateway.)

Answer (score 0):

Two hosts belong to different IP networks so (based on current scheme) they can't see each other. You need a device which can traverse and "translate" the packages from one network to other. This is usually router.

The other possible way (w/o a router) is to add static route to the other network via the network interface and you will be able to kame hosts to see each other.

Comment: No, IP subnet / prefix merely affects the subnet / prefix route that (usually) gets added automatically by the OS. What you can reach directly (with a direct route, which has no nexthop / gateway, and hence ARP resolution) is purely determined by the L2 broadcast domain itself.

Comment: @TomYan, that's good idea, will add it in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation the answer is no, the PCs cannot ping each other. They're in different subnets, so without a Default Gateway router or configuring a direct route PC *N* can only successfully ping devices with IP addresses in the range of 192.168.*N*.1-254/24.

[ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) (the protocol `ping` uses) is a [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) Layer 3 ([Network Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer)) protocol (part of Internet Layer in [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite)), and switches can only forward traffic on Layer 2 ([Data Link Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_link_layer)) using the [MAC addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

The NIC will send the packet according to the routing table of the system. What exactly will happen depends on how the IP addresses are configured. Here PC1 is pinging PC2.

1. If Default Gateway is not set, the NIC will determine the recipient is not in the same subnet and there is no next-hop gateway to send the packet to. It will drop the ICMP echo request (ping request) without forwarding.
2. If the DGW is set according to best practices as below:

   - *In this example PC1 has IP address 192.168.1.1, PC2 192.168.2.1, DGWs are configured respectively as .1.254 and .2.254*

   a. PC1 does not know the route to the DGW, so it will send out an [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) request with the broadcast MAC address (FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF). The IP address in the packet is PC1 IP, the recipient's IP is the DGW.

   b. Switch receives the packet. Because it's a broadcast packet, it will flood it out of every connected port

   c. PC2 receives the broadcast packet. It will determine the recipient's IP address is not its own, and drop the packet without responding.

Routers forward traffic using the L3 addresses (IP addresses). They are used to forward traffic between subnets (subnet is a Layer 3 concept along with IP addressing in general). In Windows world this router is referred to as Default Gateway, with *nix devices it's the Default Route. In the absence of a router, there are ways to make the communication work as described by Tom Yan and Romeo Ninov, however those aren't common practices in network design. They're special cases used in specific situations.

Because of example 1 the DGW IP address must be on the same subnet with the PC interface. Consequently in this situation the DGW must have one interface in 192.168.1.0/24 network, and another in 192.168.2.0/24. When the DGW is correctly set and present, the traffic flow is:

- PC1 sends out ARP to bcast MAC to find the DGW
- Switch floods the ARP
- DGW receives ARP packet and because it has the recipient IP, it will respond
- Switch will forward the response to PC1
- PC1 will send ICMP echo request with PC2 IP address as the recipient
- Switch will receive the echo request and forward it to the router
- Router will forward the traffic towards PC2
- PC2 will receive the echo request, and because it is the intended recipient will send the echo reply to its own DGW
- The router will receive the reply and forward it towards PC1
- PC1 will receive the packet

To study networking I'd recommend you install the free [Cisco Packet Tracer](https://www.netacad.com/courses/packet-tracer). It's Cisco Net Academy official study tool for Cisco networking exams. It allows you to build different kinds of networks using a wide variety of devices and study different kinds of traffic flows. When you run a simulation you can analyze each packet separately when it passes each interface on the route. Youtube has multiple videos teaching how to use it to create labs, from basics up to high-level Cisco exam.

Comment: `In Windows world this router is referred to as Default Gateway, with *nix devices it's the Default Route.` I don't think this is exactly a correct way to put it. Default route and default gateway aren't really the same thing conned different term by different OSes. Default route is basically a synonym to "route with the destination address of `0.0.0.0/0`", as the route is a "fallback" route that would be used when no other "more-specific" route covers a certain destination, whereas "default gateway" means "gateway (nexthop) of the default route".

Comment: Absolutely right. I'm simplifying as DGW is the expression Win users are familiar with whereas in *nix world the term is seldom used, we rather talk about default routes and next-hop routers. I'd welcome your advice on better wording :-)